# PHP: Find Location of Redirected URL

Tags: php, curl

What is the best method to find where a URL redirects to?

If using cURL `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` will follow *every* header. What I am looking to do is just find the *next* location?

My first idea was to use cURL but disable FOLLOWLOCATION and then parse the result for `Location: XXXX` but I was thinking there must be a more efficient way.

Comment: "More efficient?" That's the *definition* of where a URL redirects to.

Comment: But I would essentially just be scraping the header. Is there a way to natively do it in PHP/cURL?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` (see [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)) to 1 along with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

However, note that unless combined with `CURLOPT_HEADER`, this will result in grabbing the contents of the resource being redirected to. You don't want to do that just to find where the redirect goes.

For all that it's worth, IMO in this situation it would be better and very comparable complexity-wise to parse the `Location` header of the response instead.